# Whether we need to control for firm fixed effect when the law is at country level?

Tags: fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

From the discussion of @Thomas Bilach [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/527057/319998),

> The "group" fixed effects is technically referring to the panel unit.
> If the panel unit is firms observed over time and the policy impacts
> some firms and not others, then it is customary to estimate firm fixed
> effects.

Normally, in many papers, I saw that they mostly control for firm-fixed effects, for example, [Dasgupta, 2019](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/32/7/2587/5079300), when examining the impact of laws on countries also use the firm-fixed effects.

However, I am curious about why we must use firm-fixed effects in Dasgupta's case? Because the laws have an impact at national levels rather than specific firm levels. **I mean, from my understanding, when we examine the impact of law on firms' asset growth, we must do country-fixed effect, the firm-fixed effect is an option, not a must**. I am wondering if I fell into any fallacy.

I will rewrite the statement of Thomas Bilach based on my understanding if the panel unit is "country"

> The "group" fixed effects is technically referring to the panel unit.
> If the panel unit is **countries** observed over time and the policy impacts
> some **countries** and not others, then it is customary to estimate **countries** fixed
> effects.

Comment: The question I will ask you is: does the law affect all firms within that particular country?

Comment: @ThomasBilach , yes, the law is assumed to affect all the firms within a particular country

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most difference-in-differences (DD) applications, the unit fixed effect is specified at some *aggregate level* (e.g., city, county, state, or country level etc.). For example, if we're investigating the effects of a state level intervention on some outcome of interest, then we often estimate *state* fixed effects. Likewise, if we're examining the impact of a country level policy, then we typically estimate *country* fixed effects.

Similar to the referenced research, say we observe firms *within* countries. Anti-collusion laws may be adopted by some countries but not others, though they're designed to affect the firms within those treated jurisdictions. In other words, a firm is "treated" if it's nested within a country that passed a leniency law. Now assuming we observe the **same firms** before *and* after the law change, then we can estimate the DD coefficient with firm *or* country fixed effects. Again, it's important to highlight that we must observe firms in all pre- and post-adoption periods.

In the paper you cite, the law change is at the country level, yet it affects all firms within treated countries. Since the authors observe the same firms **over time**, before *and* after the enactment of a leniency law, then estimating *firm* and *year* fixed effects is appropriate. Why did they estimate firm instead of country fixed effects? A few justifications come to mind. The first is to account for the differences *across firms*. Note how the firm fixed effects removed all time-invariant firm level heterogeneity. The second involves *inference*. They seem particularly interested in identifying the effects of less collusion on **firms’ financing decisions**. Thus, the "firm" is the target of their inferences. Lastly, firm fixed effects may absorb more variation and likely reduced the size of their standard errors.

Peruse this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229996/difference-in-differences-with-individual-level-panel-data) for more detail on when it's appropriate to estimate fixed effects at a lower level.